# angular2 http post transform . in _

Tags: json, angular, post, request

I try to send this json to my php server `{"obj":{"r": "hello", "u": "info@email.com", "p": "123abc"}}`.

When I send that, my server receives `{"obj":{"r": "hello", "u": "info@email_com", "p": "123abc"}}`, I don't understand why.

Here is my angular code:

```
data = {"obj":{"r": "hello", "u": "info@email.com", "p": "123abc"}};

postMethod(data): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    return this._http.post(this.serverUrl, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
      .map((response:Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you are using a PHP Server.

Even if you are sending a POST request, if you send pure json, you should check over the raw input stream of PHP like:

`$stuff = file_get_contents("php://input");`

With the data you obtained from this, you can then decode data and then do your things.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Don't JSON.stringify the data in the second parameter. Angular will handle the content-type.
2. Manually set the content-type header to 'application/json'.

Comment: I've tried to not use JSON.stringify, and I haven't solve the problem.
I've changed the content-type header from 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to 'application/json', but I can't handle it with my php server

Comment: From the sound of it then, it's an issue on the PHP side. Angular automatically handles JSON conversion of body objects in a POST request and sets the content-type to application/json. What's most likely happening is your PHP side isn't receiving the application/json type properly.

Comment: You're right. It was a PHP side error. Thanks a lot!